# location based services - how to improve the location with RSSI, TA and ARFCN?

Tags: cellid

I get LAC,CellId from my device. With these values I can know the Lat/Lng and, by triangulation, the area where the device is.
I also get ARFCN, TA and RSSI. Is it possible to improve the location by using these values ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have access to cellid to lat/lng db from mobile network operator to get lat/long of your device. Other way of getting this is by using location apis provided by android, iphone etc.

Comment: That was not the question: is it possible to improve the accuracy of the position by using arfcn,ta and rssi ?

Answer (score 0):

Signal Strength could possibly give you an indication of how far from a tower you are, thus improving accuracy

What platform are you using?